# After update trigger issue

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, dynamic-soql

Please find my code below.

```
trigger PM on Account (after update) {
    for ( Account acc : Trigger.New ) {
        List<Product_Metrics_vod__c> listCon = [Select id,Products_vod__r.Name,Account_vod__c from Product_Metrics_vod__c where Account_vod__c =: acc.id];
        List<Account> accs=database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Restricted_Products_vod__c LIKE' + '%' + listCon[0].Products_vod__r.Name + '%');
        if (accs.isEmpty() == false) {
            delete listCon;
        }
    }
}
```

Please find the error message here.

> Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a
>   concrete SObject: LIST at line 4 column 93

Comment: Hi @saikat. Can you add the error message as well? This will contain a line number where the error is happening.

Comment: I am sorry please find the exact error message updated in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listcon is a list of Product_Metrics_vod__c sobjects, but you are using it as a single sobject instance in line 4:

```
List<ID> Ids=query('SELECT Id FROM Account 
     WHERE Restricted_Products_vod__c LIKE' + '%' + listCon.Products_vod__r.Name + '%');
```

Also, your query is returning a list of accounts, not IDs, so you'll need to process the returned values to extract the ids if that is what you are looking for.

If you are expecting a single entry in the list, you can access that element using the square bracket notation:

```
List<Account> accs=query('SELECT Id FROM Account 
         WHERE Restricted_Products_vod__c LIKE' + '%' + listCon[0].Products_vod__r.Name + '%');
```

I'm also duty bound to point out that you have a SOQL query embedded in a list, so you are likely to breach governor limits in the event that the trigger has to process multiple records.  You should look to bulkify your trigger - more information on this is available at:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code

Comment: Hi Bob, this soql query will every time return one record only. Will I still face governor limits?

Comment: Hi Bob. I am getting below error when trying to update Account record. My requirement is if Account ID and Product ID in Product metrics exists such that the Account record with that ID is having the same product in Restricted_Products_vod__c in Account object, then delete the Product Metrics record not restrict the update in Account.Please suggest the work around here.   Error::Trigger.PM: line 4, column 1
05:04:12.628 (628561359)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: line 1:60 no viable alternative at character '%'

Comment: I have updated the code as you suggested, it's getting no compilation error.

Comment: if you are having other issues then creating a new question is the correct thing to do. Altering your original question with the updated code now means that the code in @BobBuzzards answer is invalid.

Comment: Hi Bob, you were right there might be multiple records in Listcon those should be searched in Restricted_Products_vod__c field value of the relevant Account ID. Please suggest the workaround for that.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

> database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE
>   Restricted_Products_vod__c LIKE' +
>   '\'%'+listCon[0].Products_vod__r.Name  +'%\'');

instead of database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Restricted_Products_vod__c LIKE' + '%' + listCon[0].Products_vod__r.Name + '%');

Thanks 
Nagarjuna

Comment: Hi Nagarjuna. I am having multiple values in Listcon and I need to search all of them in Restricted_Product_vod__c field of Account ID. If exists all those records should be deleted from Product_Metrics_vod__C. Can you please suggest a workaround for that?

Comment: Also please find the main concern found with Restricted_Products_vod__c field in Account.  Link:: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13683